# How to find references to an object in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Given a collection with an object in it - I need a way to find out if this object is also member of some other collection.

I.E in some sort of pseudo code

```
object o;

Collection<object> col1;
col1.Add(o);

Collection<object> col2;
col2.Add(o);

MagicWords.GetTheReferingCollectionsTo(o);
```

Where GetTheReferingCollectionsTo should return col1 and col2.

Do anyone know of a way to accomplish someting like that in C#

Comment: Not unless the object o has a collection of collections it's been added to as a property. What's led you to this requirement? There may be a better pattern for your problem, I often find that when a particular approach seems excessively hard.

Comment: Using NHibernate and got an ObjectDeleteException - which appears, simply put, when I got two or more parents to an child object and I cannot find the other parent.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK you can't do that programmatically unless implementing your own collection with tracking references.

Comment: I believe this is the principle of Encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

If you think your app needs that, it's time to look at whether the design is sound. It likely is *not*.

I'm sure you could achieve what you want by making clever use of several `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` 'collections' and check for your object's key value by calling `ContainsKey()` on the dictionary object.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what collections to search when you call your querying method you could do something similar to this

```
   class Program {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         List<int> ints = new List<int>();
         List<int> ints2 = new List<int>();
         List<int> ints3 = new List<int>();
         for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) ints.Add(i);
         for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) ints2.Add(j);
         for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k) ints2.Add(k);

          List<ICollection<int>> rets = GetRefs<int>(3, ints, ints2, ints3);

          Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} out of {1} collections contain a reference to {2}", rets.Count, rets.Capacity, 3));

          Console.ReadKey();
      }

      public static List<ICollection<T>> GetRefs<T>(T o, params ICollection<T>[] collections)
      {
         List<ICollection<T>> ret = new List<ICollection<T>>(collections.Length);
         foreach (ICollection<T> obj in collections)
         {
            if (obj.Contains(o)) ret.Add(obj);
         }
         return ret;
      }}
```

output is: 2 out of 3 collections contain a reference to 3

Comment: That's just the problem. I don't know which collections to search in.